# Proof of indexed inverse image statement

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove that: $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda}B_{\lambda})=\bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda}f^{-1}(B_{\lambda})$

My proof: Suppose, $x\in f^{-1}(\bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda }B_{\lambda}) \iff f(x) \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda}B_{\lambda}. \iff f(x) \in B_{\lambda}, \forall \lambda \in \Lambda \iff x\in f^{-1}(B_{\lambda}),\forall \lambda \in \lambda. \iff x\in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} f^{-1}(B_{\lambda}).$

Am I correct?

Comment: It sounds good. Well done!

Comment: You may want to add the "solution-verification" tag. Your solution looks good.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSaving . I will use that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, well done! By the way, beginners should try to write a neat and formal proof (, and a beautiful layout may be also necessary). So we may organize your proof as follows.

*Proof.* It follows from

\begin{align*}
x\in f^{-1}(\bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda }B_{\lambda}) &\iff f(x) \in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda}B_{\lambda}\\
&\iff f(x) \in B_{\lambda}\text{ for all }\lambda \in \Lambda\\
&\iff x\in f^{-1}(B_{\lambda})\text{ for all }\lambda \in \Lambda\\
&\iff x\in \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} f^{-1}(B_{\lambda}).
\end{align*}